# passing a function parameter to the left hand side of an assignment r

Tags: r

I am trying to pass a function parameter to the left hand side of an assignment. For example

```
saveit <- function(name, object){
  name <- mtcars
  save(name, file="mydatabase.RData")
}

saveit("mydata", mtcars)

load("mydatabase.RData")
ls()
```

In this example, the *mtcars* data frame is save to the disk file *mydatabase.RData*, as object **name**, not object **mydata**. I can't seem to fix this and any suggestions would be welcome.

*Note: I know the renaming can occur outside the function, but there are reasons that I need it to occur within the function.*

Answer (score 2):

Use `assign`:

```
saveit <- function(name, object){  
  assign(name, object)
  save(list=name, file="mydatabase.RData")
}
```